# esptool.py not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: micropython, esptool

I recently tried to load MicroPython on *ESP8266* board, but failed. To do that I had to install esptool. I successfully installed it but when I wanted to use it, it would not work.

For instance,

```
esptool.py --help
'not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file'
```

I found many questions on this topic, but none of the answers helped me. I tried adding everything to the Windows path and it still did not work.

Comment: Have you tried (for example) `python esptool.py --help`?

Comment: I’ve resolved the problem by using ‘py -m esptool help’ command. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @OskarCvj helped me also so thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try installing esptool using pip command on Windows.
Then use only "esptool" instead of "esptool.py"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same position as the OP.
On Windows 10 I must use this syntax at a CMD prompt launched as an admin:

```
py -m esptool --help
```

I'm running Python 3.10.2 and esptool was installed using

```
py -m pip install --user pip
```

Comment: WIndows 11:   python -m esptool version

Answer (score 1):

pip3 install esptool (Administration Mode)

Problem :

C:\WINDOWS\system32>esptool --chip esp328266 -p COM3 erase_flash
'esptool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

AFTER DOING THIS

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install esptool

Collecting esptool
Downloading esptool-3.1.tar.gz (175 kB)

----------Successfull----------------------

C:\WINDOWS\system32>esptool.py --chip esp8266 -p COM3 erase_flash
esptool.py v3.1
Serial port COM3
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: e8:db:84:9b:5a:57
Uploading stub
Running stub
Stub running
Chip erase completed successfully in 2.7s
Hard resetting via RTS pin...

Comment: I needed to use `esptool.py` for a script - this surprisingly works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use
https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json
in board manager

DO NOT USE
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json
Gives eror
'/esptool.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33950084)

Answer (score -2):

By using "esptool -h" I could check the help option.

Comment: this wouldn't help in the op's case